# Reload ImageView by URI on ListView

Tags: android, android-listview, android-asynctask

I have a [ListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html) of elements composed with [ImageView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html). I get a new image using an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) and in the [onPostExecute(Object result)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onPostExecute(Result)) method I set the image using [setImageUri(Uri uri)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageURI(android.net.Uri)) but it doesn't gets updated.

If I change of activity or between apps, image is shown perfectly, but I want to show the image immediately.

I tried calling `invalidate()` with all the combinations of the `ImageView`, the extended `BaseAdapter`, the parent `ListView`, but nothing worked. I tried many other techniques like calling `setImageResource(0)`, `setImageUri(null)`, but no results...

**EDITED:**

Here, part of the code:

```
public class ThingItemAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    protected List<Thing> things;
    LayoutInflater inflater;

    public ThingItemAdapter(Context context, List<Thing> things) {
        this.things = things;
        this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return things.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Thing getItem(int position) {
        return things.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return things.get(position).getId();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final int pos = position;

        final ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = this.inflater.inflate(R.layout.thing_list_item, parent, false);
            holder.thingImageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.thing_preview);
            holder.button = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.apply_button);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        final Thing thing = things.get(position);
        final long thingId = thing.getId();

        final Uri thingUri = thing.getPicture();
        holder.thingImageView.setImageURI(thingUri);

        holder.button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // generate new file
                final TypedFile typedFile = new TypedFile("multipart/form-data", new File(thingUri.getPath()));

                new ReadAndStorePictureTask()
                        .execute(new Object[] { typedFile, holder.thingImageView, thing });
            }
        });

        // item detailed view listener
        holder.thingImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent((ThingApplication) ThingApplication.getContext(), ThingActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra(ThingActivity.EXTRA_THING_ID, thingId);
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        ImageView thingImageView;
        ImageButton button;
    }

    private class ReadAndStorePictureTask extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, Void> {

        ImageView imageView;
        Thing thing;
        ViewGroup parent;

        protected Void doInBackground(Object... params) {

            final TypedFile typedFile = (TypedFile) params[0];
            imageView = (ImageView) params[1];
            thing = (Thing) params[2];

            ((ThingApplication) ThingApplication.getContext()).getClient().apply(typedFile,
                    new Callback<Response>() {

                        @Override
                        public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
                            ...
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void success(Response nothing, Response response) {
                            try {
                                byte[] bytes = ThingApplication.getBytesFromStream(response.getBody().in());
                                Uri newImageURI = Uri.parse("uri://valid_uri"); // whatever, it exists in real code
                                thing.setPicture(newImageURI);
                                File file = ((ThingApplication) ThingApplication.getContext())
                                        .getFileFromURI(newImageURI); // this method works

                                ThingApplication.saveBytesToFile(bytes, file.getAbsolutePath());
                                thingService.storeThing(thing);
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                ...
                            }
                        }

                    });
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            imageView.setImageURI(thing.getPicture());

            // force redraw. FIXME not working          
            /*
            * ANSWER HERE, PLEASE
            */

        }
    }
}
```

**How can I show the updated URI immediately inside `onPostExecute(Object result)` method?**

Comment: i think, you have used notifyDataSetChanged();, then you should show some of you code, so that i can help you

Comment: @Androider code added.

Answer (score 0):

onPostExecute you update the list of images that it's linked to the ListView adapter and after that you notify the adapter that you changed the items in the list by calling:

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: if you paste your adapter i'll try help you

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

-Change third parameter in asynctask call.

```
new ReadAndStorePictureTask().execute(
    new Object[] { typedFile, holder.thingImageView, pos });
```

-Then, modify the list items inside asynctask and refresh.

```
private class ReadAndStorePictureTask extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, Void> {

        ImageView imageView;
        int position;
        ViewGroup parent;

        protected Void doInBackground(Object... params) {

            final TypedFile typedFile = (TypedFile) params[0];
            imageView = (ImageView) params[1];
            position = (Integer) params[2];

            ((ThingApplication) ThingApplication.getContext()).getClient().apply(typedFile,
                    new Callback<Response>() {

                        @Override
                        public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
                            ...
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void success(Response nothing, Response response) {
                            try {
                                byte[] bytes = ThingApplication.getBytesFromStream(response.getBody().in());
                                Uri newImageURI = Uri.parse("uri://valid_uri"); // whatever, it exists in real code
                                things.get(position).setPicture(newImageURI);
                                File file = ((ThingApplication) ThingApplication.getContext())
                                        .getFileFromURI(newImageURI); // this method works

                                ThingApplication.saveBytesToFile(bytes, file.getAbsolutePath());
                                thingService.storeThing(things.get(position));
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                ...
                            }
                        }

                    });
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
```

Good luck!

Comment: not working. if you see, it is the same, I'm passing a 'thing' that is extracted form the position. it is the same getting it outside or inside the AsyncTask.

Comment: Its possible that postExecute() run before doInbackground() finish, because method new Callback<Response> run in other thread.

Comment: yesss!!! that is the exact reason. I changed the code to do synchronous calls. edit your answer with this exact comment and I will check it as correct ;)